# Using each_slice to produce a table but with sub headings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using each_slice to output a two column table.

I would like to insert a title row when an attribute of the elements I am iterating changes.

I have :

```
all_users = Users.order('category, name asc').all
all_users.each_slice(2) do |two_users|
    <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right">
              <%= two_users[0].category + ' - ' + two_users[0].name %>
            </td>
           <% if two_users[1].present? %>
            <td>
              <%= two_users[1].category + ' - ' + two_users[1].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
            <% else %>
            <td></td>
            <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

And would like something like :

```
current_category = ''
all_users = Users.order('category, name asc').all
all_users.each_slice(2) do |two_users|
        <% if two_users[0].category != current_category 
         current_category = two_users[0].category
    %>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><%= two_users[0].category %></td></tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right">
              <%= two_users[0].name %>
            </td>
           <% if two_users[1].present? %>
            <td>
              <%= two_users[1].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
            <% else %>
            <td></td>
            <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work obviously in the case that two_users[1] has a new category.
I am trying to avoid the additional SQL queries of iterating through each category and requesting
the users for each independantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_users.each_slice(2).with_object({cc: nil}) do |two_users, memo|
  if category = two_users.detect { |u| u.category != memo[:cc] }
    # print additional row or do whatever here
    memo[:cc] = category
  end
end
```

[`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) here returns either changed category or `nil` if there were no changes.

*Sidenote*: Try to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
<td>
  <%= two_users[1].name if two_users[1].present? %>
</td>
```

Comment: Mudasobwa, I have played around with this suggestion and not been able to get it to work. I believe memo[:cc] = category should be memo[:cc] = category.category. Also I don't think it will work because if each of the two users in an iteration has a different category the first new category will be printed and the second user will be outputted under the first user's category heading. Thanks